# Why is $\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} (2r+1)r=\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} 4\binom{r}{2} + 3\binom{r}{1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

- How did the summation expression get transformed to combination?
- From where did the constants $4$ and $3$ come from?

$$
\begin{align*}
T(m^2-1) &= \sum_{r=1}^{m-1} (2r+1)r\\ &=
\
\sum_{r=1}^{m-1} 4\binom{r}{2} + 3\binom{r}{1} \\ &=
4\binom{m}{3} + 3\binom{m}{2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: $\binom r2=\frac 1 2(r^2-r)$ and $\binom r1=r$. Then it is just a matter of calculation.

Comment: See [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula#Examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the fact that the binomial coefficients form a *basis* for the space of polynomials; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficients_as_a_basis_for_the_space_of_polynomials .

In this case in particular, the easiest way to derive the result is likely going coefficient by coefficient.  In general, ${r\choose k}$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $r$; since $(2r+1)r=2r^2+r$ is of degree 2, we should start with ${r\choose 2}$.  A quick look at coefficients shows that ${r\choose 2}=\frac12r^2-\frac12r$, so $4{r\choose 2}=2r^2-2r$ and $(2r+1)r=4{r\choose 2}+3r$.  But ${r\choose 1}$ is just $r$, so we end up with $(2r+1)r=4{r\choose 2}+3{r\choose 1}$.

The point behind making this change of basis, incidentally, is the next step in evaluating the sum: for any $k$ we have $\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}{r\choose k}={m\choose k+1}$, so once the terms of the original sum have been transformed into binomial form, we can 'collapse' the sums of binomial coefficients into a single binomial coefficient each.

Answer (score 3):

$(2r+1)r = 2(r-1)r + 3r = 4\binom{r}{2} + 3\binom{r}{1}$

Answer (score 2):

Do you know $\sum_{r=1}^n r^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

and $\sum_{r=1}^n r=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$

also for integer $n,r\ge0,$

$$\binom nr=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)}{r!}$$

consequently, $\binom n2=\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$ and $\binom n1=n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\binom r1 =r\qquad &\Rightarrow r=\binom r1\\
\binom r2=\frac {r(r-1)}2\qquad &\Rightarrow r^2=2\binom r2+\binom r1 \end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}(2r+1)r&=\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}2\left[2\binom r2+\binom r1\right]+\binom r1\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}4\binom r2+ 3\binom r1\qquad \blacksquare \\
&=4\binom m{3}+3\binom m2
\end{align}$$

NB -

1. transforming the summand into combinatorial format (or binomial coefficients) makes it easier to sum as you can use the identity $$\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom ra=\sum_{r=1}^{m}\binom ra=\binom {m+1}{a+1}$$
2. if you require a numerical value for the final result, it will be faster to calculate it using the combinatorial format

Comment: what does the black square mean?

Comment: It's a halmos, or end-of-proof indicator. It was placed there as it concludes the proof of your original question. The next line was just to complete the summation in explicit form.